# Issue in displaying store multi-select drop down in custom module

Tags: multistore, stores, store-id

I have a custom community module in which I want to allow store multi-select drop-down.

I am already displaying the drop-down but when I save it's value and then, if I edit the form, I don't see the selected value highlighting though the value is stored correctly in database.

Can anybody let me know, what am I missing in the form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add this in to your Form.php

```
$fieldset->addField('store_id','multiselect',array(
            'name'      => 'stores[]',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('banners')->__('Store View'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('banners')->__('Store View'),
            'required'  => true,
            'values'    => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getStoreValuesForForm(false, true)
        ));
```

and you must have function in your module with `_afterLoad` function

```
class Mage_Banners_Model_Mysql4_Banners extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {    
        // Note that the banners_id refers to the key field in your database table.
        $this->_init('banners/banners', 'banners_id');
    }


 protected function _afterLoad(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{

    $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
        ->from($this->getTable('banners_store'))
        ->where('banners_id = ?', $object->getId());

    if ($data = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchAll($select)) {
        $storesArray = array();
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $storesArray[] = $row['store_id'];
        }
        $object->setData('store_id', $storesArray);
    }

    return parent::_afterLoad($object);

}
```

above code is just for your help you can set it as per your column name and database tables

Comment: Where should I put this function?                             I am using "MySQL4/Collection" approach instead of "ResourceDB/Collection" approach for model-collection.

Comment: @Vivek. Added new class you can use it like above